# Angularjs validate dynamically added selects

Tags: angularjs, validation

I'm making a directive to add persons.

The requirement have been to set the numbers and then the age and gender of the persons.

So my directive have select-dropdowns.
The first 0 to 10 to set the numbers of persons. 
When that change I have a $watch that adds person-objects to an array.

```js
$scope.$watch('selectedAntal', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if (!newValue) {
    return;
  }

  for (var i = $scope.anonymousPersons.length; i < newValue; i++) {
    $scope.anonymousPersons.push({
      gender: 0,
      birthYear: -1
    });
  }

  updateNumber($scope, newValue, 10);
});
```

In my html-view I have a ng-repeat for the select-dropdowns for gender and
birthYear.

```html
<label for="numberOf_{{name}}">Choose number of persons</label>

<select name="numberOf_{{name}}" ng-model="selectedAntal" ng-options="x for x in antal" ng-required="true">
    <!--<option value="" default style="display: none;">Choose</option>-->
</select>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Birth year</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in anonymousPersons">
            <td>
                <select name="{{name}}_{{$index}}_gender" ng-model="person.gender" ng-options="x.text for x in genders" required >
                    <option value="" default style="display: none;">Choose</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="{{name}}_{{$index}}_birthYear" ng-model="person.birthYear" ng-options="x for x in years" required >
                    <option value="" default style="display: none;">Choose</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                {{person|json}}
            </td>
            <td><button ng-click="remove(person)">Remove</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

All works fine except the validation. The selects for gender and birthYear both have required set.

But the validation doesn't work.

My guess is that Angular don't know anything about the newly created fields, but the $dirty field works.

How should I add it to validation of manually run the validation?

[I have now made an example on plnkr that demonstrates the problem.](https://plnkr.co/edit/vXH5E3lE2o7tfGnK18rZ)

Comment: What is written in validate() function?

Comment: Required should work fine for dynamically generated fields. Are you checking for the $invalid flag in your validation?

Comment: @Pavan The ng-change="validate()" was a rest from an attempt to do it manually. I had just missed to remove it.

Comment: @Carlos13 I am printing the form in the view that uses this directive. I can se the new fields as they appear. But they ar valid. The $dirty flag switches from false to true when I have switch the focus away from the field.

Comment: Edited the post and added a link to a plnkr example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validation works, but the problem is that you intialize your select models with some values. In that case the 'require' is solved. If you initialzie ng-model with null you don't have some trouble.